# Is there a way to call a python script, which modifies an xml using ElementTree, from c# code?

Tags: c#, xml, python-3.x, ironpython, elementtree

I have a implemented a python script which modifies a local xml file by getting values from another local xml file, using `ElementTree`. I need to implement a GUI for the entire thing. So, I chose **Visual C# > Windows Desktop > Windows Forms App**. Here I could make a simple GUI, where the code calls the python script using IronPython. It seems that IronPython does not support `ElementTree`. Here is where the issue is.

Using Visual Studio Community 2017. So, added Python Development while installing it. Also, in the project references, added IronPython using "Manage Nuget Packages". But could not add python there, as it said

> "Could not install package 'python 3.7.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Irrespective of this, python code was running by creating engine. But when the python script which used elementtree was run, I got the error

> "Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
>   No module named xml.etree.ElementTree".

Although the code runs perfectly fine, when run directly from a python shell.
After that I googled and found a way:

```
paths.Add(@"C:\Users\suddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib");
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```

But now the new error is:

> "Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
>   unexpected token 'from'"

FullInstallation.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IronPython.Hosting;

namespace Installer
{
    public partial class FullInstallation : Form
    {
        public FullInstallation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
                        paths.Add(@"C:\Users\suddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib");
        engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
            try
            {
                engine.ExecuteFile("I:\\Python\\XML     Parser\\BW_Config_ConfigureCode.py");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Python script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Welcome! In this file, we configure all the tags of BW_Config.xml, which are there in the file BW_Config_Installer_Configurations.xml
# We parse 2 xml files in this code.
# First is the BW_Config.xml which we need to configure
# Second is the BW_Config_Installer_Configurtion.xml which contains the information about which tags are to be configured in the BW_Config.xml

BW_Config_tree = ET.parse('BW_Config_for_parsing_practice.xml')  # parsed BW_Config.xml
BW_Config_root = BW_Config_tree.getroot()

# parsed BW_Config_Installer_Configurations.xml
installer_config_tree =ET.parse('BW_Config_Installer_Configurations.xml')
installer_config_root = installer_config_tree.getroot()
i = 0
# This loop will traverse all the tags which need to be cofigured, one by one
for configurable_tag in installer_config_root.findall("./BW_Config/"):
    # This variable will contain the name of the tag to be configured in each iteration
    configurable_tagname = configurable_tag.tag
    # This variable will contain the path of the tag inside BW_Config.xml, in each iteration
    configurable_tagpath = configurable_tag.attrib["xpath"]
    # This variable will contain the data about what is to be configure in the tag, in each iteration
    configurable_tagattribute = configurable_tag.attrib["property"]
    # This variable will be set to "yes", if the respective tag is to be changed, else "no"
    configurable_tagchoice = configurable_tag.attrib["configurable"]
    # This variable will contain the new value for the respective tag
    configurable_tagnewvalue = configurable_tag.attrib["value"]
    i = i + 1  # It is used just to maintain the number of iterations and for user friendly console display
    # Printing which tag we will be dealing with in this iteration
    print(i, configurable_tagname)
    print("\n")
```

....

How to use python(with elementTree), that is being called from c#?
Or is there a different way, other than IronPython, or anything else?

Comment: Does IronPython 3.x even exist? It seems like 2.7.9 is the latest version. https://ironpython.net/

Comment: You are right. IronPython version is 2.7.9.0 in the project's references. So, is that a problem.